# React component generic type expected 0 type arguments but got 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
type TCommonField = {
  label?: string,
  dataKey?: string,
  required?: boolean,
  loading?: boolean,
  placeholder?: string,
  getListOptionsPromissoryCallback?: unknown,
  listingPromissoryOptions?: unknown,
  renderOption?: unknown,
  getOptionLabelFormat?: unknown,
  onChange?: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown,
  validationCallback?: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown,
}

export type TField<fieldTypeT = any> = FC<TCommonField & fieldTypeT> & {
  types?: Record<string, unknown>,
};
```

I'm creating a type declaration for `Field` function component with `TField` type. Field is a function component to render different types of fields(select, autocomplete, text field...)

There are common fields which all fields shared, so I've created `TCommonField` type, and there're some specific fields per fields.

I've created `TField` type with generic `fieldTypeT`, so that each Field can pass the type and it will be combined with common types.

```
<Field<{ tabIndex: number }>      => Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
  dataKey="dataKey"
  placeholder="Some place holder"
  tabIndex={-1}
/>
```

Field is a JS component

```
declare function useForm<formValuesT = Record<string, unknown>>(
  initialValues?: formValuesT,
  config? : TUseFormOptions
): TUseFormResponse<formValuesT>;

type TUseFormResponse<formValuesT = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  values: formValuesT,
  isPassing: boolean,
  formError: string | null,
  fieldErrors: TFieldErrors,
  dataHasChanged: boolean,
  triggerScrollCheck: () => void,
  setServerErrors: TServerErrorCallback,
} & { Field: TField };
```

[Updated typescript lang with two fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBUBhXECAOwDFgkAbAEzgBeOAG9ycOLxQAjPgH4AXHADOMKMHYBzADQS4YaWiQALCAKRQlq9Zt3kAvpSQAPSLDg06jbn34AeTB4BBlokBgA%20YURiGAA6TiZ-ZlYOXwE4ADI4IL9QukissX0vJBVrZDRoALUNbR04AFd2AGt2CAB3dgi9BwoqMMYAVRUkTmgQZBVIdlHA4P588IbMCYA1FF5GsoZoyur-WrsG5rbO7qiRcUkAN03tlWVVqBANrZ29SXT%20ZQZv%20byYUivX6-CQaGkRByzQwwA4TVG4xeAJCQJW63uOz24IOR3qTVa7S6EQiAAp9JpgDBgJs3g9rM9XpiVAw9ABKX4jMYTKYzOa5VEFdEvOk7CL9KqzeAAEWARAwACEIBAWnYAOrAABeKCgghEpLZwii1zgkrUYm%20DmijURE38ohgsgAkuwwS5lOxGiA5FAHA1RHA7u9rHitHAHGTRA42f1KJIiDBGlB2HByZJJP4Ivp03AAPS5xiueDfbPp-wlnM56RyXhCfDVvj4Us5wzoUzmMFQOut4xmCxQJuV9OOmQut1CUQAWgAjE4h7ms828wWAIKNGAQKrgXhIGD0b5wJflhZLyQN2v12R8OAAJkHQ4MRnb-e7T77ndv96HMi2UAA8uwADKfDgjAE6YJsoxzpWC6lv4sGSGyjhAA)

[image]

Comment: Please show how you're defining `Field`.

Comment: Updated. `Field` is a  javascript react component, retunred from `useForm` hook. I've added the form hook response type delcaration.

Comment: Okay - could you maybe add a minimal example that exhibits this behavior on e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ? (You can use `react` types over there too, it will implicitly import them from definitelytyped.)

Comment: I've added the link

Comment: In your example (which isn't minimal, by the way), you don't give `TField` a generic argument at all, so it defaults to the `= any` or `= void`...

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to specify `fieldTypeT` in `useForm`, so it can return the correct type of `TField`.

[This typechecks out fine.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBUBhXECAOwDFgkAbAEzgBeOAG9ycOLxQAjPgH4AXHADOMKMHYBzADQS4YaWiQALCAKRQlq9Zt3kAvpSQAPSLDg06jbn34AeTB4BBlokBgA+YURiGAA6TiZ-ZlYOXwE4ADI4IL9QukissX0vJBVrZDRoALUNbR04AFd2AGt2CAB3dgi9BwoqMMYAVRUkTmgQZBVIdlHA4P588IbMCYA1FF5GsoZoyur-WrsG5rbO7qiRcUkAN03tlWVVqBANrZ29SXT+ZQZv+byYUivX6-CQaGkRByzQwwA4TVG4xeAJCQJW63uOz24IOR3qTVa7S6EQiAAp9JpgDBgJs3g9rM9XpiVAw9ABKX4jMYTKYzOa5VEFdEvOk7CL9KqzeAAEWARAwACEIBAWnYAOrAABeKCgghEpLZwii1zgkrUYm+DmijURE38ohgsgAkuwwS5lOxGiA5FAHA1RHA7u9rHitHAHGTRA42f1JEQYI0oOw4OTJJJ-N99GmpLI+EJ8NI5Lx8Fm04Z0KZzGCoPny8YzBYoCXs5JHTIXW6hKIALQARic2YA9BF9GzHEA)

```
import React from 'react';

type TCommonField = {
  label?: string,
  placeholder?: string,
}

export type TField<fieldTypeT> = React.FC<TCommonField & fieldTypeT> & {
  types?: Record<string, unknown>,
};

type TUseFormResponse<fieldTypeT, formValuesT = Record<string, unknown>> = {
  values: formValuesT,
  Field: TField<fieldTypeT>,
};

declare function useForm<fieldTypeT, formValuesT = Record<string, unknown>>(
  initialValues?: formValuesT,
): TUseFormResponse<fieldTypeT, formValuesT>;

const DirectBookingWizard = () => {
  const {Field} = useForm<{tabIndex: number}, { value?: string }>({});

  return (
    <Field
      label='label'
      placeholder='placeholder'
      tabIndex={-1}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice, I've modified your typescript lang to render different Fields with different `fieldTypes`. That's exactly what I want. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to quite fly :) You could use an union type for an "either/or-sets-of-props", but it's going to be type-unsafe at some point, I'm afraid.